# DC backup battery switching module

Tags: batteries, dc, backup

It is common to find these cheap Backup Battery Switching on the internet. But the issue I have with these ones is the load gets reset when switching from the main source to the battery. It seems like there is a delay during switching of the relay. Could this be improved by designing a transistor-based switch?

[image]

Comment: Could this be improved?  Yes. Does that answer your question?

Comment: MOSFET- based ORing controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems like there is a delay during switching of the relay.

The relay is a "break-before-make" type switch. This results in a momentarily cut of the load's supply.

> Could this be improved by designing a transistor-based switch?

You have a few options. These two came to my mind:

- Have a circuit that is a type of "make-before-break" -- can be done with either mechanical elements (relays) or semiconductors (diode power-ORs or MOSFETs).
- Placing a sufficiently large capacitor across the load's supply so that it keeps supplying the load during the momentarily cut -- this can be impractical as the required capacitance can be tens of thousands of micro-Farads.